# Check automatically in background if Wi-Fi network connection is enabled

Tags: java, android, networking, android-wifi

I am working on an application that is going to need to communicate with electrical plugs. These electrical plugs will be inside a specific network called "EPlugs Network" (for example).

I need to check automatically and continously if the connection to this network is still enabled.

If a Wi-Fi network is available, I need to check if this is the good one. I suppose it will be enough to just catch the name of said network.
If it is not the good one or if no Wi-Fi connection is enabled, I will need to create a pop-up and ask the user to connect to this specific network. Otherwise, the application should not be able to continue working.

Is there a native way to check Wi-Fi connection's presence?

Thank you for your help.